# Get the text of selected checkbutton- tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a gui in tkinter, I have 3 Checkbuttons:

```
    var1 = IntVar () #assing variable for the model selection- user select PLS
    Checkbutton (top, text="PLSR", variable=var1).grid (row=11,column=1,sticky='W' )
    var2 = IntVar () #user select RF model
    Checkbutton (top, text="Random forest", variable=var2).grid (row=12, column=1,sticky='W' )
    var3=IntVar () #user select SVR model
    Checkbutton (top, text="SVR", variable=var3).grid (row=13, column=1,sticky='W')
```

I want to get the **text** (PLSR/RF/SVR) of the **selected** checkbutton. If the user select the first, I want to print PLSR and so on.
I know the method cget("text") but how I know which checkbutton selected from the three?(only one can be selected)

Comment: You can set the `onvalue` to the same as the text of `Checkbutton`.

Comment: but I still need to know which button selected. how do I know this?

Comment: If you set `offvalue` to None or `""`, then you can use the values of the `StringVar` to know which checkbuttons are checked.

Comment: If you want only one can be selected, you should use `Radiobutton` instead of `Checkbutton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command as below then simply read values of "whichButton" to determine which button is selected.

```
whichButton = ""
    
def command1():
       global whichButton
       whichButton = "PLSR"
       print(whichButton)

    
def command2():
       global whichButton
       whichButton = "Random forest"
       print(whichButton)

def command3():
       global whichButton
       whichButton = "SVR"
       print(whichButton)

Checkbutton (top, text="PLSR", variable=var1,command=command1).grid (row=11,column=1,sticky='W' )

Checkbutton (top, text="Random forest", variable=var2,command=command2).grid (row=12, 
        column=1,sticky='W' )

Checkbutton (top, text="SVR", variable=var3,command=command3).grid (row=13, column=1,sticky='W')
```

Comment: You are missing `:` for the definition of the functions.

Comment: thanks for your suggesiton, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try radiobutton function.
like this
`python var1 = StringVar() #variable var1 = Radiobutton(text="Paid", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 15),variable=var1,value="Paid").place(x=520, y=290)`

Answer (score 0):

Checkbuttons are for performing multiple choice. If you want to allow the user to only make a single choice you should use Radiobutton. Not just because that's how tkinter is designed, but because the distinction between radiobuttons and checkbuttons are universal and well understood by most users.

When you use two or more radiobuttons, they should all share the same value. To determine which button was selected you just have to get that one variable. If you want to get the string rather than an integer, use `StringVar`

```
var = StringVar(value="PLSR")
Radiobutton (top, text="PLSR", variable=var, value="PLSR")
Radiobutton (top, text="Random forest", variable=var, value="Random forest")
Radiobutton (top, text="SVR", variable=var, value="SVR")
```

With the above code, when you get the value of the variable you will get either "PLSR", "Random forest", or "SVR".

[image: screenshot]